# Performance of executing function within render - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I have a stateless functional component that renders the same structure of components over and over.  I'd like to instead create a function that will prevent me from having to repeat myself.  Will I incur a performance hit if I execute a function within my return? :

```js
const Example = props => {
  return {
    <div>
      Title 1
      {data1}
    </div>
    <div>
      Title 2
      {data2}
    </div>
    <div>
      Title 3
      {data3}
    </div>
    <div>
      Title 4
      {data4}
    </div>
  }
}

// vs.

const Example = props => {
  function customComponent(title, data){
    return (
      <div>
        {title}
        {data}
      </div>
    )
  }

  return (
    customComponent(Title 1, data1)
    customComponent(Title 2, data2)
    customComponent(Title 3, data3)
    customComponent(Title 4, data4)
  )
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you're asking us to spend our free time benchmarking this for you?

Comment: What is the difference of `Test` and `customComponent` except one is lower cased? Just make it a component by passing a props object and give it a meaningful name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should extract the markup into its own functional component in that case:

```
const CustomComponent = ({title, data}) => (
    <div>
        {title}
        {data}
    </div>
);
```

Then you can do:

```
const Test = props => {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <CustomComponent title="Title 1" data={data1} />
            <CustomComponent title="Title 2" data={data2} />
            <CustomComponent title="Title 3" data={data3} />
            <CustomComponent title="Title 4" data={data4} />
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

It is not very clear where your data comes from. Assuming you have your items in an array passed as prop then you can just render it like:

```
const Test = props => {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            {props.items.map(({title, data}) => (
                <CustomComponent title={title} data={data} />
            ))}
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

This is everyday business in react. If a component contains repetitive jsx extract a new component. There is very litte performance penalty if any and you should not worry as long as it is not too slow in your real app.

Comment: The reason why I chose not to go about this way is that it creates a layer of abstraction with the new `<CustomComponent>`.  I'd rather have a customComponent function since I can readily see what that function is doing.  Is there harm in my approach?

Comment: @MiddleZ I can't really see why this would be less readily. Also abstraction is most of the time a very good thing to do. And the "harm" of using a plain function is that react doesn't know it's a component and can't do diffing in the shadow dom and you also can't debug and inspect it as well. In the end functional components are nothing else then functions anyway but you need to keep to the conventions of react if you want it to be treated as a component.

Comment: What I was trying to avoid is having to navigate to another file and scan through a component to see what it does.  I also think writing out multiple lines of components as opposed to array.map is easier to read.  Finally, my data is coming from props but it has to be validated and is not part of an array that can be readily mapped.

Comment: @MiddleZ You can define as many components in the same file as you like. There is no such requirement to have a separate file for every component. You also do not need to use `map()` if it does not meet your requirements. It is just an example. using `map` for rendering data of the same shape is common practice and very readable. As I don't know your application I just guessed that could be helpful for you. And where is the problem in validating the data before rendering? And what is the difference in scanning a function vs scanning a component? A functional component **is** a function.